# Struts 2: Getting one tag value in another tag

Tags: forms, struts2

I have a struts 2 `select` element. I want to pass selected index value through `url`, Here's the code:

```
<s:select id="courseId" 
     headerKey="-1"
     headerValue="Select Course"
     list="coursesMap"
     name="courseId" theme="simple"/>
```

I want to access selected index in following tags (inside same form)

```
<s:url action="checkSeatsAvailability.do" var="iUrl" >
    <s:param name="requestStatusId">**HOW TO GET SELECTed INDEX VALUE HERE or in VALUE attribute**</s:param>
</s:url>
<a href="<s:property value="#iUrl"/>">Check Seats</a>
```

Please suggest how can I get it working. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Struts Tags are processed *SERVER SIDE*, ***BEFORE*** the page is rendered. Use javascript for this.

Comment: Or create a form and submit it.

Comment: Inside the form nothing is selected until you set the value for the index.